# How to add an array to my line data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) that shows the tracked usage over time. I gather all of my chart information into arrays that I now want to use with my chart. The only problem is that I am not sure how to do it. I have included my variables and for loop so show that information is being populated correctly. I have also included my data information with comments of where I want to put each of the Arrays.

These are my variables and how I am create my array:

```
//variables to use 
var ArrayForDailyUsage = [];
var ArrayForTotalUsage = [];
var theTotalUsageSoFar = 0;
var ArrayForTheDate = [];
var ArrayForHoldingTheUsageInformation = [];
var usageplan = 1024;
```

This is how I set up my data for a line graph:

```
var data = {
    labels: //This is where I want to add ArrayForTheDate[]
        ["Aug 1", "Aug 2", "Aug 3", "Aug 4", "Aug 5"],

    datasets: [{
            label: "Usage Plan",
            fillColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)", //adds the color below the line
            strokeColor: "rgba(224,0,0,1)", //creates the line
            pointColor: "rgba(244,0,0,1)", //gets rid of the circle
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: //this is where I want to add my ArrayForHoldingTheUsageInformation[]
                [usageplan, usageplan, usageplan, usageplan, usageplan]
        }, {
            label: "Overall Usage",
            fillColor: "rgba(48,197,83,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            data: //this is where I want to add ArrayForTotalUsage[] 
                [15, 25, 45, 70, 80]
        }, {
            label: "Daily Usage",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: //this is where I want to add ArrayForDailyUsage[]
                [15, 10, 20, 25, 10]
        }
    ]
};
```

In case you were wondering, this is how I add my chart

```
var maxUsage = 1024;
var maxSteps = 5;

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    pointDot: false,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: maxSteps,
    scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(maxUsage / maxSteps),
    scaleStartValue: 0
});
```

Why can I not do: labels:ArrayOfDates[];

Is there a simple way to add my arrays to my chart data? How do I approach this? Thank you in advance! Please let me know if I was unclear or if you have any questions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it that you just want to use the arrays you declare in the setup of your data? If so you can just reference them directly

```
var data = {
    labels: ArrayForTheDate,

    datasets: [{
            label: "Usage Plan",
            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)", //adds the color below the line
            strokeColor: "rgba(224,0,0,1)", //creates the line
            pointColor: "rgba(244,0,0,1)", //gets rid of the circle
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: ArrayForHoldingTheUsageInformation
        }, {
            label: "Overall Usage",
            fillColor: "rgba(48,197,83,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            data: ArrayForTotalUsage
        }, {
            label: "Daily Usage",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: ArrayForDailyUsage
        }
    ]
};
```

here is a fiddle usign some data to show it working http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/35o54t2L/